# redirect user to specific pages depend on the text given on input form

Tags: php, html, jquery

im newer to php tried to redirect user to specific pages depend on the text given on input form

i have an input with a button and php

```html
<input type="text" name="code" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```html
$pages = array(
    '123-admin-com' => 'alledite.php',
    '211-moderator-com' =>'halfedite.php',
    '056-coroot-com' => 'edite.php'
);

if(isset($pages[$_POST['code']])):
    $page = $pages[$_POST['code']];
endif;

header('Location: ' . $page);
```

this work only redirect user to `alledite.php` if user put full text `123-admin-com` what I want is to let user redirect to `alledite.php` even user put anything is random before `-admin-com` for example user put random text before `-admin-com` like

`jhyjhgh-admin-com` or `g0g646dfg-admin-com` or any random text that is before `-admin-com` than redirect to `alledite.php` so i need something to validate `-admin-com`

I want the same things on others `211-moderator-com` and `056-coroot-com`

hope you guys understand me thanks in advance

Comment: What is the PHP version?

Comment: @AmirMB why would matter the PHP version?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It matters because if OP's using PHP 8.0, str_ends_with method can be used, otherwise a custom implementation is required

Comment: Why have you tagged your question as [jQuery]? Do you want to perform a *navigation* using JS or on FORM submit and server-side header stuff?

Comment: @Amir MB does not matter for me just give me the solution if you know it

Comment: @MedLamine I already gave you the solution but it does matter because some methods are not available on previous version of PHP so if you are using an older one you can't use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach might be to use a `regex` - and I know there are others out there far, far better at writing killer regex patterns than I.

```
<?php
    # for test porpoises
    define('BR','<br />');
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['code'] ) ){
        # set $displayonly=false to actually do the redirection
        $displayonly=true;
        
        
        $code=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'code',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $code=str_replace('-','.',$code);
        
        $pages=array(
            '@admin-com'            =>  'alledite.php',
            '@moderator-com'        =>  'halfedite.php',
            '@coroot-com'           =>  'edite.php'
        );
        
        foreach( $pages as $str => $redirect ){
            # construct a basic regex pattern from the array key.
            $pttn=sprintf( '/((.*)?%s)/', preg_quote( str_replace( '-', '.', $str ) ) );
            
            # for testing
            if( $displayonly )echo $pttn . BR;
            
            # Run the regex and if a match is found use the corresponding
            # value from the above array as the redirection endpoint.
            preg_match( $pttn, $code, $matches );
            if( !empty( $matches ) ){
                $header=sprintf('Location: %s', $redirect );
                exit( $displayonly ? $header : header( $header ) );
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Match string and redirect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='code' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As it appears to be the latter piece of any string that you wish to match in order to perform the redirection the array of strings to endpoints was modified to remove unnecessary strings.

Comment: thanks for the help i like the idea of regex can you provide me code of regex if i would use (at)admin.com not -admin-com i know the change is in  '@((.*)?%s)@' but as im beginner on php get very hard to figur it pls if you can provide the code for (at)admin.com  (note symbol at not allowed more than one time due to tag system i use (at) as example very thanks

Comment: You are the best, i really appreciate it you solved my problem with your great script  Thankyou :)

Comment: sorry forget about something if user put any email that is not (at)admin-com or (at)moderator-com or (at)coroot-com should redirected to one file 'ignored.php' please can you add this in the code i searched alot can't figure it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, you need to check if the input ends with one of the identifiers:

```php
$pages = array(
    '-admin-com' => 'alledite.php',
    '-moderator-com' =>'halfedite.php',
    '-coroot-com' => 'edite.php'
);

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    foreach ($pages as $id => $page) {
        if (endsWith($code, $id) { // if PHP 8.0 str_ends_with can be used 
            header('Location: ' . $page);
            //exit or return or ...
        }
    }
    //handle the case when $code is not valid
}
//handle the case when $_POST['code'] is not set

function endsWith ($string, $needle) {
    return substr($string, -$length) === $needle;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the code isn't work for me it keep saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in C:\AppServ\www\web\admin\board.php on line 32 i tried many time nothing happen but my original code on my question its worked this the error line is  if (isset($_POST['code']) { can you pls take a look thanks

Comment: I need to know the PHP version

Comment: i use PHP Version 5.6.30 using appserv localhost software

Comment: @MedLamine that PHP version is out of support. You should have upgraded years ago. You're leaving your site (and your users, and their data) potentially vulnerable to unfixed problems in that old version. Speaking frankly:  it's irresponsible and negligent to run such an old version. See https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php for the latest support info

Comment: The fault is likely due to the missing brace from `if (isset($_POST['code']) {` - that should be `if (isset($_POST['code'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

Put your html code inside the FORM tag, just like:

```
<form action='redirect.php' method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name="code" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Moreover, place the following code before your IF case.

```
$page = "default_page.php"; //in case user providing a value does not exists in array, redirect to this page
if(isset($pages[$_POST['code']])):
    $page = $pages[$_POST['code']];
endif;
```